# Create human voice frequency with Console.Beep c#

Tags: c#, frequency, voice

Male voice covers a Frequency range of 100Hz to 8KHz. can i create A sequence of different frequencies in Console.Beep to create a word? Console.Beep support 37 - 32767Hz. (The rage frequencies are suitable for frequencies of human voice).
for example

```
Console.Beep(100, 220);
Console.Beep(90, 130);
Console.Beep(125, 240);
Console.Beep(192, 150);
Console.Beep(200, 120);
Console.Beep(90, 130);
Console.Beep(125, 240);
Console.Beep(132, 150);
Console.Beep(200, 220);
Console.Beep(190, 230);
Console.Beep(185, 240);
Console.Beep(192, 250);
```

Comment: Yes, although the "words" are unintelligible. Running your code gave me a good laugh.

Comment: This is just an example. To say one word I need thousands of lines. And of course not in such a way that it will work very slowly. thank you for the answer (The question seemed a little strange so I got a lot of negative scaling straight at first even though the question is most logical)

Comment: If you really want to do this, there are better ways https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I want it read in Hebrew. There is no library or update for Hebrew reading anywhere so i should try to build alone

Comment: Gotcha. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

The second parameter is the duration in milliseconds, and it's an integer, which means the minimum duration you can specify is 1ms, which means that the maximum theoretical sample rate you could achieve via this method would be 1,000 Hz.

That's already probably too low for speech (see the table of commonly used sample rates [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(signal_processing)#Sampling_rate)), but more importantly, the practical limit is going to be much lower. `Console.Beep` isn't meant for use in this way. Even when I use it to play a tone with a relatively long duration (say, one second), there's an audible "click" at the end when the sound abruptly stops. When I try a long series of consecutive calls with durations of 1ms or even 10ms, those clicks are all I hear. You'll need to use an audio library of some kind instead.